# Is it possible to plug in third-party Svelte Components at runtime?

Tags: svelte

I'm building analytical dashboard. And would like to provide for users a way to use custom components.

The custom components also going to be Svelte components. But the important thing is that they should be plugged in as a separate JS/CSS files, without the need to re-build the whole dashboard JS/CSS build.

I know it's possible with React, where the component is just a JS class. Is that possible with Svelte?

Comment: For sure. Svelte is a compiler that produce vanilla JS code, these’s no reason you can’t. Only problem is how. So how would you like the usage/interface to be?

Comment: FYI https://svelte.dev/repl/16b375da9b39417dae837b5006799cb4?version=3.25.0